# How to display error message for null value using noty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a task to do some assignments using noty js. I am new in noty.
How can I display error message for null value.
The code is

```
$('#name').focusout(function(){
    var value = $('#name').val();
    alert(value);
if(value == '')
var n = $('#name').noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n43Z9/)
Is there any working examples or demos using noty js?. Please help

[Referred site:[noty.js](http://needim.github.io/noty/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
$('#name').focusout(function()
{
    var value = $('#name').val();
    if(!value)
        noty({text: "It's null!"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`''` would refer to an empty string, whereas `void 0` means there's litterally *nothing there*.

```
$('#name').focusout(function(){
    var value = $('#name').val();
    alert(value);
if ((value === void 0) || (value === ''))
var n = $('#name').noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
    });
```

Note that I'm using `===` here for a *strict comparison*, rather than the usual `==`. For this scenario it probably won't really matter, but it might save you some headaches once you get to more complicated stuff.